# left join optimisation

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, left-join

I have a database similar to the simplified one below. I need to retrieve columns: col8, col9, col10, col11, col12 (the ones I've circled

Currently, I;m using a left join to join each table but this results in the query taking a very long (there are lots of records). Upon profiling, the biggest impact is writing to the tmp table.

I'm limiting the result to 24, but because of the left joins it's still copying thousands of records to the tmp table.

http://oberto.co.nz/demo/assets/db2.jpeg

Can this be optimised to still retrieve the circled column from each table using joining by the pk?

Thanks.

Comment: Good image;-) But we still do not know anything about your tables and indexes. I want to say that all fields used to join tables (ON clause) should be indexed with a primary key, unique key or just with a simple index.

Comment: haha, thanks. I just updated it to make it *hopefully* clearer. The first column of each table is the primary key and each joining tables has a corresponding foreign key.

Comment: @Devart - +1. If indexes are properly applied, the query should be quite fast, unless there is something else involved (order by? group by? having?). Left joins do not perform any worse than inner joins. Can we maybe see the query you're using and what indexes are where?

Comment: @Jarrod: [sample code](http://sscce.org/) is much more helpful than pictures when it comes to programming questions. Please post sample table schema (`CREATE` statements), sample data (as `INSERT` statements) and the query you're trying to optimize.

Comment: Agree with others, your question is still a bit vague. So far, I think, you can only have guesses, not answers. You might well be satisfied to receive guesses, of course, but people might not me satisfied to make ones. Anyway, could it be that both `B` and `E` can have multiple matches per `A`'s row? If that's the case, you may be getting many duplicates.

Comment: I too agree, and also, more specifically with @AndriyM, you refer to LEFT join going down stream to "A->B->C->D->" and "A->E".  Are there required entries in any of these "b, c, d, e" tables, if so, which ones.  Additionally, which can have 1 to many relationships that could cause duplications...  And finally do you have any filtering criteria, such as in ANY of the tables where you are looking for specific values.  Such as from Table B where column 3 must be some value or range.  This would imply that the record MUST exist in table B and no "left join" would be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.col12, b1.col8, c1.col9, d1.col10, e1.col11
FROM a
INNER JOIN (SELECT b.col8, b.col2, b.col3 FROM b 
            WHERE b.col2 = a.col2 GROUP BY b.col8) b1 
        ON (b1.col2 = a.col2)
INNER JOIN (SELECT c.col9, c.col3, c.col4 FROM c 
            WHERE c.col3 = b1.col3 GROUP BY c.col9) c1 
        ON (c1.col3 = b1.col3)
INNER JOIN (SELECT d.col10, d.col4 FROM d 
            WHERE d.col4 = c1.col4 GROUP BY d.col10) d1 
        ON (d1.col4 = c1.col4)
INNER JOIN (SELECT e.col11, e.col6 FROM e 
            WHERE e.col6 = a.col6 GROUP BY e.col11) e1 
        ON (e1.col6 = a.col6)
```

Now you will have no more duplicate rows.
You may have to experiment with `LEFT` instead of `INNER` joins.
And if you don't need a subselect you should eliminate it, because it slows things down.

Answer (score 0):

in its current and simplest form, I would have the query as...

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      a.col1,
      a.col12, 
      b.col8, 
      c.col9, 
      d.col10, 
      e.col11
   FROM a
      left join b
         on a.col2 = b.col2
         left join c
            on b.col3 = c.col3
            left join d
               on c.col4 = d.col4
      left join e
         on a.col6 = e.col6
```

However, will adjust once I read back on other criteria, filters, conditions, left/inner join "requirements" that may help optimize further.